# Using an expression in a JMS Selector in Mule 3

Tags: activemq-classic, mule

I want to get a queue:

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="jmsConnector" queue="queue.dev" >
<jms:selector expression="JMSCorrelationID='353'"/>
</jms:inbound-endpoint>
```

It works but I want to use an expression in the selector:

```
<jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="jmsConnector" queue="queue.dev" >
<jms:selector expression="JMSCorrelationID='#[header:OUTBOUND:codeReport]'"/>
</jms:inbound-endpoint>
```

It's no working.

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't make sense: you are trying to use an outbound property in an inbound endpoint. This can not work.

Where is the value for `codeReport` supposed to come from? If a properties file then use `${codeReport}`.

EDIT: It turns out that, based on the OP's comments, the solution is to use a requester on the JMS queue, not an inbound endpoint. The following code demonstrates requesting messages until the queue is empty and returning them in a `java.util.List`:

```
<scripting:component>
    <scripting:script engine="groovy"><![CDATA[
        def jmsMessages = []

        for (def muleMessage = muleContext.client.request("jms://out.queue.dev?selector=JMSCorrelationID%3D'"+ message.getInboundProperty('codeReport') +"'", -1L);
             muleMessage != null;) {
          [] << muleMessage.payload
        }

        jmsMessages
    ]]></scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
```

Comment: The variable `codeReport` is a param from rest (is a dynamic variable).

it's can't a property.

The `jms:selector` is a inbound-endpoint's property. `http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/JMS+Transport+Reference#JMSTransportReference-ExampleConfigurations`.

Comment: The flow has an `http:inbound-endpoint` and run it from my test with `client.send("http://localhost:8177/customerUpdate?codeReport=351", "", prop);`

Comment: Mmmh OK but I would have preferred you edit your question and show the full flow with the HTTP and JMS endpoints. What is not clear at all is what do you want to do with the messages coming from your JMS inbound endpoint?

Comment: I want put in my Component and execute business logic.

Comment: So in summary: the HTTP request will provide `codeReport` and will also start an JMS listener. After that, all messages received on the JMS queue and that match the selector will be processed by a component. What happens if a second HTTP request comes in? Do you want to start another listener? Even if `codeReport` is the same?

Comment: Ok this is my flow:
`<flow name="ReprocessingUpdateFlow" doc:name="Reprocessing">
<http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="${http.host}" port="${http.port}"  path="${http.path.customerUpdate}" doc:name="HTTP"/>
....
   <flow-ref name="GetQueuesDevUpdateFlow" doc:name="Flow for obtaing queue value"/> 
</flow>
<flow name="GetQueuesDevUpdateFlow" doc:name="UpdateFlow">
<jms:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="jmsConnector" queue="out.queue.dev" >
<jms:selector expression="JMSCorrelationID='#[header:INBOUND:codeReport]'"/> 
</jms:inbound-endpoint>
<echo-component />
</flow>`

Comment: Updating your question would have been better than posting XML in a comment. You still haven't specified what you want to happen. Looking at your flow it seems to me you actually do not want to start a JMS listener but in fact you want to consume a single message from the JMS queue + selector when the HTTP request comes it. Is that it?

Comment: i want simply consume the message (or messages) from jms in the component. But this message(s) is was filtered by CorrelationId.

Comment: So you want to consume all the pending messages that match the selector? Do you want to wait for any more messages or stop consuming as soon as there are no more messages? And you want to return a response based on these messages to the HTTP client? How do you want to aggregate these messages into a unique response to the HTTP client?

Comment: Yes, I want to consume all the pending messages that match the selector, and stop when there aren't more messages.

The response will be a map.
The correlationId is compound, and i want to put it  in the data base.

Comment: I finally understood what you want to do and reviewed my answer.

Comment: now i can't connect to my jms.  `tcp://localhost:61616@${payload.User}:${payload.Password}//inbound.out.queue.dev`
the property give problems `jms.password=p4$$w0rd`

these are data on my server, i can't change.

Comment: Do you have several JMS connectors configured?

Comment: no, only one. `<jms:activemq-connector name="jmsConnector" specification="1.1" brokerURL="${jms.brokerUrl}"  validateConnections="true" doc:name="Active MQ" />`
but, i can use it in groovy code?

Comment: If there is only one JMS Connector configured, the above code should work without any problem. Have you validated that your JMS connector is correctly configured? For example, can you successfully use a JMS inbound or outbound endpoint in a test flow?

Comment: yes i can. 
i test inbound and outbound flow JMS, and working.

Comment: So I don't get your problem. Do you get an exception? If yes, pastebin it please.

Comment: i'm sorry, for late. Finally I did it in java with `jmsTemplate` and it works

Comment: That's uncool because it can work in Mule too, I did it before :(

Comment: this is the error :
Script2.groovy: 3: illegal string body character after dollar sign;
   solution: either escape a literal dollar sign "\$5" or bracket the value expression "${5}" @ line 3, column 58.
    `://localhost:61616@admin:p4$$w0rd//queue `

I'll try it with mule.

Comment: What's this string? The content of the `codeReport` query parameter you're passing to the HTTP endpoint?

Comment: this is your component with my values:
   <scripting:component>
       <scripting:script engine="groovy"><![CDATA[
            def jmsMessages = [] 
            def url = "tcp://localhost:61616@${jms.username}:${jms.password}//inbound.out.queue.dev" 
            for (def muleMessage = muleContext.client.request(url+"?selector=JMSCorrelationID%3D'"+ message.getInboundProperty('reportCode') +"'", -1L); 
                 muleMessage != null;) { 
              [] << muleMessage.payload 
            } 
            jmsMessages 
        ]]></scripting:script> 
   </scripting:component>

Comment: But I thought you wanted to retrieve from a **JMS queue**, why did you change my code to use the **TCP connector**?

Comment: Use my code as-is and pastebin both your flows and the full stack trace you're getting.