# jms selector expression in Mule is not working

Tags: jms, mule, mule-studio

```
<flow name="readqueueFlow1" doc:name="readqueueFlow1" >
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="MyTestQueue" connector-ref="Active_MQ-Priority" doc:name="JMS">
        <jms:selector expression="JMSCorrelationID=’353’" />
    </jms:inbound-endpoint>
</flow>
```

Its working but when i try to use the below one its not deploying

```
<!-- When we don't provide single quote it is failing in deployment -->
<jms:selector expression="JMSCorrelationID='#[flowVars.reqId]'" />

<!-- Payload contains reqId, when we provide it in single quote, it is assuming as a constant -->
<jms:selector expression="JMSCorrelationID='#[payload]'" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here is your answer given :- [Using an expression in a JMS Selector in Mule 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15375953/using-an-expression-in-a-jms-selector-in-mule-3)

And one more thing, you cannot use `#[flowVars.reqId]` for getting the `jms:selector` value dynamically since flow variable scope is limited to a flow ... instead use a **session variable** like `#[sessionVars.reqId]`..

and your flow will be modified as follow :-

```
 <flow name="readqueueFlow1"  >
    <jms:inbound-endpoint queue="StudioOUT" connector-ref="Active_MQ" doc:name="JMS"/>
       <scripting:component>
    <scripting:script engine="groovy"><![CDATA[
        def jmsMessages = []

        for (def muleMessage = muleContext.client.request("jms://MyTestQueue?selector=JMSCorrelationID%3D'"+ sessionVars['reqId'] +"'", -1L);
         muleMessage != null;) {
      [] << muleMessage.payload
        }

        jmsMessages
    ]]></scripting:script>
</scripting:component>
  <logger level="INFO" message="#[message.payload]" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

You can see here the message is send to the queue using Groovy Script and I have used **session variable** instead of **flow variable**

Answer (score 0):

jms:selector expression="putOnQueueTime > ABC "

can use the above expression in jms inbound.